# scrapy pagination not following the link to next page

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

So I was following a tutorial online but the content is outdated. I'm stuck as to why it doesn't scrape the next page? here is the code.

Also I set the ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

```
import scrapy


class EcigPageSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ecig_page'
    allowed_domains = ['www.cigabuy.com/']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.cigabuy.com/consumer-electronics-c-56_75-pg-1.html'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.xpath("//div[@class='p_box_wrapper']"):
            title = product.xpath(".//a[@class='p_box_title']/text()").get()
            url = product.xpath(".//a[@class='p_box_title']/@href").get()
            discounted_price = product.xpath(".//div[@class='p_box_price cf']/span[1]/text()").get()
            original_price = product.xpath(".//div[@class='p_box_price cf']/span[2]/text()").get()

            yield {
                'title': title,
                'url': url,
                'discounted_price': discounted_price,
                'original_price': original_price,
            }

        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@class='nextPage']/@href").get()

        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

I also tried changing the if next page: body to

`yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)`

still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I get it now it's just I need to remove that extra "/" in this line

`allowed_domains = ['www.cigabuy.com/']`

make sure not to include that slash